Do separable cubic constraint and separable quartic constraint SOCP presentable?
I am an engineer who is doing some network modeling and optimization. During my work, I was running into a case that is quite strange. The problem that I am trying to solve seems to be convex and it can be readily solved by any general convex solver:
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {\min }\limits_{x,y,z,t,y} }&{x + y + z + t + y}\\
{}&{{a_1}{x^3} + {a_2}{y^3} + {a_3}{z^3} - t \le 0}\\
{}&{{b_1}{x^4} + {b_2}{y^4} + {b_3}{z^4} - y \le 0}\\
{}&{x + y + z + t + y \ge 1}\\
{}&{...{\rm{and}}\,{\rm{some}}\,{\rm{linear}}\,{\rm{constraints}}}
\end{array}
Here, all $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ are positive numbers and all decision variables are non negative since they are some physical quantities.
However, in practice I see that SOCP (or QP) problem can be solve very fast by exploiting their structure. Out of pure curiosity, my question is:
Do the following separable cubic constraint and separable quartic constraint SOCP presentable ?
${{a_1}{x^3} + {a_2}{y^3} + {a_3}{z^3} - t \le 0}$
${{b_1}{x^4} + {b_2}{y^4} + {b_3}{z^4} - y \le 0}$
My initial guess is that, it is very likely since Mosek has mentioned something about power cone and exponential cone. However, I dont know how to actually do this.
An interesting example is here:
Proving the set $\left\lbrace \frac{(x + y)^2}{\sqrt{y}} \leq x - y + 5, y > 0 \right\rbrace$ is convex
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

$t\geq x^2$ is SOCP, and therefore also $t\geq x^4$ by composing two of those ($t\geq y^2, y\geq x^2$) and $t\geq x^3$ is equivalent to $tx\geq y^2, y\geq x^2$, both of which are SOCP.

Every respectable modeling tool (CVXPY, CVX, Yalmip) will perform this reformulation for you behind the scenes.

Note that the formulation of $t\geq x^3$ will force/require $x$ to be nonnegative.

Thank you so much ! Could you make a step by step official answer so that I could accept it ?

In general, for every rational number $r=p/q>1$ the inequality $t\geq x^r$ is convex on the set where $x\geq 0$ and it can be modeled using second-order cones. The model depends on $p,q$ and gets bigger as $p,q$ grow, so at some point it becomes easier to write this constraint using a more general power cone as in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html#powers . The power-cone representation works uniformly for all real $r>1$.
However for small values of $p,q$, and especially $q=1$ as in this case, the representation with second-order cones is reasonably nice. For example $t\geq x^4$ is equivalent to $$t\geq y^2,\ y\geq x^2$$ where both inequalities describe a rotated quadratic cone (https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#rotated-quadratic-cones). Similarly $t\geq x^3$ is equivalent to $$tx\geq y^2,\ y\geq x^2$$ where again we have two rotated quadratic cones.
The general model of $x$ to an integer power follows by induction: $$t\geq x^{2n} \iff t\geq y^2,\ y\geq x^n,$$
$$t\geq x^{2n-1} \iff tx\geq y^2,\ y\geq x^n.$$

Thank you so much ! I have to embeded on real electronic device. Therefore, it is very helpful to be extremely clear like this one !

I just have one question, can I do it like this ${x^3} \le t \Leftrightarrow \left{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{xy \le t}\
{{x^2} \le y}
\end{array}} \right.$

No, $t\geq xy$ is not convex, yet alone conic. That's why the slightly tricky and at first nonintuitive approach to fit it into the right form.

Thank you so much, it was quite difficult !

I almost forgot, if have negative power (${x^{ - 2n}} \le t$ or ${x^{ - 2n - 1}} \le t$ ) then how can I use your formula ? This is because in my application sometimes things got inverted. :(

$t\geq x^{-m}$ is $t\geq z^m$ combined with $zx\geq 1$.
